# Passenger is preventing Bundler from seeing my git gems

Tags: nginx, deployment, phusion-passenger, rvm, bundler

I'm attempting to deploy a Rails 3.1 application to an Ubuntu 11.04 server running nginx-1.0.0 and passenger-3.0.7

I have a system-level RVM install at `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180`

My nginx.conf looks like:

```
http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/passenger-3.0.7;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180/ruby;

    # ...

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my-domain.com;
        root /srv/www/my_project/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have two gems in my Gemfile that point to git repos. Bundler says that they are installed, they are present in RVM's gem directory, but Passenger throws an error:

```
git@my-domain.com:my-gem (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

Running `rails console` from the deployment directory works fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Changed deployment script to use `bundle install --deployment`, the `--deployment` option installs gems into `vendor/bundle` instead of the system directory.